# Using Arduino Yún to send data through Ethernet

Tags: ethernet, arduino-yun

I'm still new to Arduino Yún and I can't find any tutorials or examples on making the Yún send data through Ethernet, which will then be showed on a web server.

I've seen other tutorials but they use Uno with an Ethernet shield.  Is it the same with the Yún too?

How can I send data through Ethernet using Yún?

Answer (score 1):

There are three bits of information you need to know:

1. The Ethernet port is connected to a tiny Linux computer
2. On Linux you can do HTTP POST and HTTP GET using a program called cURL
3. The AVR chip can tell the Linux computer what to do using the `Process` library.

Putting all those together: You need to use the `Process` library to tell Linux to run `curl` with the right parameters.

Just like the tutorials show you:

- https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Process